# Logstash with Elasticsearch: I am using logstash to ingest the data into the ES index. But now I want logstash to run 24/7

Tags: elasticsearch, service, logstash

```
    #file:db.conf

input { 
    jdbc { 
           jdbc_driver_library => ""
           jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
           jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@abcd.klm.uvw:1521/qtp1"
           jdbc_user =>"user_wew"
           jdbc_password => "password_wew"

           
           
                  statement => "select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, countid,max(version) as mv from master_object_table where version >:sql_last_value group by countid"

            schedule => "* * * * *"
           last_run_metadata_path => "C:/ES1/ELK_stack_7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-7.4.2/Master_refresh_a.txt"

           use_column_value => true

            tracking_column => "version"

         } 
       }
       
        filter {
      mutate {
        convert => {
          "countid" => "string"
          }
          }
          }
       
output {
  elasticsearch { 
           hosts => "localhost:9200" 
           index =>"refresh_index_a"
           document_id =>"%{countid}"
           #document_type="_doc"
           
           }
 file {
         path => "C:\\ES1\\ELK_stack_7.4.2\\logstash-7.4.2\\logstash-7.4.2\\bin\\logstashESRecordsIngestionDetails_refresh_a.txt"
         
         codec => rubydebug
       }
           
  stdout {   codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Above is my logstash config file setting. I want to run this logstash 24/7 and also if the machine shutsdown on which this logstash is running  then how can I manage that as this logstash is ingesting the live data to ES index. Please suggest. **Is there any way if one server goes down the logstash on another node will continue the work.**

Comment: Hi @Gibbs thanks for the response. I am not using Beats...instead I am using Logstash.

Comment: Hi @Gibbs thanks for the response. I am not using Beats...instead I am using Logstash. I just want to run the logstash all time 24/7  also need to know about failure mechanism .  In second point below as you mentioned that two logstash nods are recommended ...how can i scale it and how it will insure failure mechanism

Comment: First of all you should configure logstash to run every certain period of time and of course install logstash as a service.  Then you could use persistent data to store the information on disk instead of keeping it in memory.  Finally divide the logstash load into multiple nodes to secure the load.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html#_scalability)

> Logstash is horizontally scalable and can form groups of nodes running
> the same pipeline. Logstash’s adaptive buffering capabilities will
> facilitate smooth streaming even through variable throughput loads. If
> the Logstash layer becomes an ingestion bottleneck, simply add more
> nodes to scale out. Here are a few general recommendations:
>
> 1. Beats should load balance across a group of Logstash nodes.
> 2. A minimum of two Logstash nodes are recommended for high availability.
> 3. It’s common to deploy just one Beats input per Logstash node, but multiple
>    Beats inputs can also be deployed per Logstash node to expose
>    independent endpoints for different data sources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...so Beats is necessary to implement Failover mechanism Or is there any mechanism we can do it